# Difference between ipad 2 and ipad 3 default Browsers?

Tags: ipad, safari

What are the two versions of Safari called?

What are the difference in terms of development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the iPad 2 and the 3rd gen iPad are actively supported by Apple, they use the same default browser - Mobile Safari 6.

Comment: How do you know -- I can't find anything about this within apple dev?

Comment: Use an iPad 2 and an iPad 3 on a site that checks the user agent string - they're the same.

Comment: They do use the same browser but there are minor differences in the rendering engines.  I wish I knew all of them, but for example background images are handled slightly differently between the two.